# Is this the correct way to ask "What time do you get up in the morning?"

Tags: questions

I have read many versions of this question, but I am unable to find an underlying pattern. Here is my version:

> Le matin tu te lèves à quelle heure ?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Il y a plusieurs manières de poser cette question, par exemple :

1. Le matin, tu te lèves à quelle heure ?  (Attention aux accents)
2. À quelle heure est-ce que tu te lèves le matin ?
3. À quelle heure te lèves-tu le matin ?

   La question 1 est surtout utilisée à l'oral, en langage familier. Par contre, la question 3 est la forme la plus soignée.

Ce ne sont que trois exemples. Il y a, bien sûr, maintes autres possibilités.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!